# rails & postgreSQL - How can I update a data with existing primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to update some data in `Lecture(id, name, etc.)` table.

For example, there is a data(`id: 1, name: "first"`) in the `Lecture`.

When I typed `Lecture.create(id: 1, name: "newer")` =>

#### `PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "lectures_pkey"`

Is there any way to update data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "lectures_pkey"

`id` is the default ***primary key*** which shouldn't be ***changed*** or ***duplicated***. As you are inserting a row with an existing id, you get that error.

Instead, you need to do like below.

```
@lecture = Lecture.find(1)
@lecture.update_attributes(name: "newer")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`Lecture.find(1).update(name: "newer")`

Find more information on update here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update

The reason it didn't work is because the id is unique. When you were using create, it was trying to create a NEW record with id of 1, not edit the same record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> lec = Lecture.find(1)
>
> lec.update_attributes(name: "newer")

You are getting error **PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "lectures_pkey"** due to you can not create record with same id. Id is primary key in table.

Answer (score 0):

All of the current answers are correct if you don't mind loading the record and then updating it.  If you don't need to actually load the record, and just want to update data in the database you can do

```
Lecture.where(id: 1).update_all(name: "newer")
```

This will skip all validations, etc and just do a direct sql update of the data in the database of the record with id == 1

Comment: Tom Walpole Thank you! :)